# find max value of a child object

Tags: javascript, json, max

What would be an elegant way to find the max value of a child object in javascript?

Example:

find the max quantity value of this object (here shown as json):

```
{"density":[
  {"price":1.22837, "quantity":48201},
  {"price":1.39837, "quantity":28201},
  {"price":1.40107, "quantity":127011},
  {"price":1.5174,  "quantity":75221},
  {"price":1.60600, "quantity":53271}
]}
```

thank you for any advice!

PS: just to clarify: of course i could loop through, but i thought there would be a more elegant way ...

Comment: i'm sorry, did not recognize ...

Comment: Is this actually an object or a JSON string?

Comment: it is a json that represents the object that will be searched for the max ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the `reduce` method of the Array prototype:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(objstring)["density"];
var max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
   return Math.max(a, b.quantity);
}, 0);
```

Another solution would be something like

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr.map(function(item){
   return item["quantity"];
}));
```

For more "elegant" ways there are functional libraries which provide getter factory functions and more Array methods. A solution with such a library could look like

```
var max = arr.get("quantity").max();
```

which would do exactly the same as the above one, but nicer expressed.

Comment: `reduce` is a great, simple, and elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way other than looping thru, because you need to visit every child in order to see if the `quantity` parameter is the new max.  In other words, the complexity of the problem is O(n).  If the children were ordered by quantity, it would be a different story (i.e. just get the first or last child in the list.)

something like the following...

```
var json = '{"density":[{"price":1.22837,"quantity":48201},{"price":1.39837,"quantity":28201},{"price":1.40107,"quantity":127011},{"price":1.5174,"quantity":75221},{"price":1.60600,"quantity":53271}]}'

var x = JSON.parse(json);
var max = 0;

x.density.forEach(function(item){
    if (item.quantity > max) max = item.quantity;
});
```

After this runs, max is the max quantity

note you didn't give us correct json, so I tweaked it a bit.

Here is an example -- click run and look in your console http://jsfiddle.net/e3dQe/

Answer (score 0):

How about the max() method? But first you would need to collect all the values in an array...

```
var obj = // your object
var values = new Array();

for (key in obj) {
  values.push(obj[key])
}

var max = values.max()
```

Not much more elegant, but a different solution.