# Min and max in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My array is:

```
var a = new Array();
a[0] = {x: 10,y: 10};
a[1] = {x: 20,y: 50};
a[2] = {x: 30,y: 20};
a[3] = {x: 10,y: 10};
```

`var min = Math.min.apply(null, a.x)` doesn't work.
Some ideas?

Comment: `a.x` is not defined, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [find max value of a child object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839417/find-max-value-of-a-child-object)

Comment: this is a coords system, i want to max X min X max Y and min Y with a simple code

Comment: Yes, and the duplicate shows how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had the right idea with `.apply` but you need to pass a collection of the `x` values.

```
var xVals = a.map(function(obj) { return obj.x; });
var min = Math.min.apply(null, xVals);
```

---

The `.map()` method makes a new Array comprised of whatever you returned in each iteration.

```
[10, 20, 30, 10]
```

---

Then passing the Array as the second argument to `.apply` will distribute the members of the Array as individual arguments. So it's as though you did this:

```
Math.min(10, 20, 30, 10) // 10
```

---

But since you need to `.map()`, you might as well skip the `Math.min`, and just use `.reduce` instead.

```
var min = a.reduce(function(min, obj) { 
                      return obj.x < min ? obj.x : min; 
                   }, Infinity);
```