# Find min and max value in csv file

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, 2d, max

Looking to extend my javascript object, I want to find the minium and maximum of a multicolumn csvfile. I have looked up solutions but I cannot really grasp the right way. I found a solution here: [Min and max in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042887/min-and-max-in-multidimensional-array) but I do not get an output. 
My code that I have for now is here:

```
function import(filename)
{
var f = new File(filename);
var csv = [];
var x = 0;
if (f.open) {
    var str = f.readline(); //Skips first line.
    while (f.position < f.eof) {
        var str = f.readline(); 
        csv.push(str);
    }
    f.close();
} else {
    error("couldn't find the file ("+ filename +")\n");
}


for (var i=(csv.length-1); i>=0; i--) {

        var str = csv.join("\n");

        var a = csv[i].split(","); // convert strings to array (elements are     delimited by a coma)
        var date = Date.parse(a[0]);

        var newdate = parseFloat(date);
        var open = parseFloat(a[1]);
        var high = parseFloat(a[2]);
        var low = parseFloat(a[3]);
        var close = parseFloat(a[4]);
        var volume = parseFloat(a[5]);

        var volume1000 = volume /= 1000;
        var adjusted_close = parseFloat(a[6]);

    outlet(0, x++, newdate,open,high,low,close,volume1000,adjusted_close); //    store in the coll  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**
What if, instead of an array of arrays, you use an array of objects? This assumes you're using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
var outlet=[];
var outletkeys=['newdate','open','high','low','close','volume','volume1000','adjusted_close'];
for (var i=(csv.length-1);i>0; i--) {
    var a = csv[i].split(","); 
    var date = Date.parse(a[0]);
    var volume = parseFloat(a[5],10);

outlet.push( _.object(outletkeys, [parseFloat(date,10) ,        parseFloat(a[1],10) ,        parseFloat(a[2],10) ,        parseFloat(a[3],10) ,        parseFloat(a[4],10) ,        parseFloat(a[5],10) ,        volume /= 1000 ,        parseFloat(a[6],10) ]) );
}
```

Then the array of the column 'open' would be

```
_.pluck(outlet,'open');
```

And the minimum it

```
_.min(_.pluck(outlet,'open'));
```

**Edit2**

Let's forget about underscore for now. I believe you need to get the maximum value on the second column, which is what you put in your `open` variable.

¿Would it help if you could have that value right after the for loop? For example

```
var maxopen=0;
for (var i=(csv.length-1); i>=0; i--) {
    var a = csv[i].split(","); 
    var date = Date.parse(a[0]);
    var newdate = parseFloat(date);
    var open = parseFloat(a[1]);
    maxopen=(open>maxopen)? open : maxopen; // open overwrites the max if it greater
    ...
    ...
    outlet(0, x++, newdate,open,high,low,close,volume1000,adjusted_close);
}
console.log('Maximum of open is',maxopen);
```

Comment: I am using the for loop to churn out the contents of the array in reverse order. I start with a multicolumn csvfile where I delete the first row (header) and then read the data in reverse order. The data then go out through outlet 0.
I want the maximum of column 2 (and I suppose then I can alter the function to look up the minimum as well).

Comment: I edited my answer to use underscore methods pluck, object and min. Give it a try!

Comment: I had to finish another project so this stayed under the radar. I am getting back at it but I cannot grasp how do you do it. Where do I have to put your code in my code? Also, what does the 10 mean, where did you get that number? What does outlet.push mean? I am using outlet as an outlet of a box containing the code in maxMSP.

Comment: Adding to my comment: As I am using JS in MaxMSp, I cannot use the underscore library. Could you post your previous answer so I can try that out?

Comment: 10 is the radix parameter. The right way to use parseFloat needs a radix, but it defaults to 10 anyway. I have never heard about MaxMSp, but is sounds as if it has an internal js parsing engine. Are you sure it can't be extended with modules? Even webworkers can import third party libs.

Comment: So what should I download to install underscore.js? On the Github page i downloaded a jsfile but what do I do with it? I will try to get it on my system but then the question is what happens if somebody else wants to use my application?

Comment: Here goes a link to the app I am making (just the relevant part). You drop a csvfile on the droprectangle and the js object reads it. I included a short csv file so you can test it right away: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a09818a7fnhys56/ft-vP6R6Ot
It is mac only

Comment: I'm sorry I took the overkill approach. Perhaps what you need is much simpler and I didn't consider to start with the simplest scenario. ¿Can you please see my **Edit2** paragraph?

Comment: That seems to be working. I will expand it to use with the other variables and then I will post the full code. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother once again: How would I get the minimum of each column? I cannot declare the initial value as 0 because the end result would always be 0. This statement does not work: minopen=(open<minopen)? open : minopen;
So the initial value should be non-zero but how do I deal with that?

Comment: It's valid to declare ```var minopen=-Infinity;``` so anything would be greater than its initial value.

Comment: I am trying to build a similar statement as to get the maximum values but that does not work. I have declared var minopen=-Infinity; before the loop and inside the loop I am trying statements like: minopen=(open>minopen&&open<maxopen)? minopen : open;
But that gives me the last value in the column. Other statements gove me -inf as a result.

Comment: Got it: I had to make a separate loop and use var minopen=Infinity;
as the variable, then inside the loop reading the array and there put    minopen=(open<minopen)? open : minopen;