# finding d3 extent of multiple values in object array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data array:

```
var data = [{glazed: 3.50, jelly: 4.50, powdered: 1.00, sprinkles: 3.50, age: 21, responses: 2,name:"test"},
    {glazed: 2.83, jelly: 3.50, powdered: 1.83, sprinkles: 4.50, age: 22, responses: 6,name:"test"},
    {glazed: 3.25, jelly: 4.75, powdered: 2.25, sprinkles: 3.50, age: 23, responses: 4,name:"test"},
    {glazed: 1.50, jelly: 4.00, powdered: 2.50, sprinkles: 4.00, age: 25, responses: 2,name:"test"}];
```

If I wanted to find extent of either glazed or jelly or powdered or sprinkles to use for scaling, I would use a code as below..

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                    return d.glazed;//or jelly etc..
                }))
                .range([0, width]);
```

What would I need to do to get the extent of all values in glazed, jelly, powdered and sprinkles rather all values which are not age, responses and name.

This is because json file gets created dynamically and so I will have no idea of the key values except age, responses and name.

So, my requirement is that it should give me min as 1.5 (from glazed) and max as 4.75 (from jelly)

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: just do checks to see which one is the maximum/minimum and return that ?

Comment: Normally I would do that .. create a temp array and push in it the values of known keys and get an extent but in this case I do not know the name of the keys as well,

Comment: look up how to find highest value in two dimensional array

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042887/min-and-max-in-multidimensional-array but they are checking for min and max in X and Y separately

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function (item) {
        return (item.glazed);
   })))
   .range([0, width]);
```

`map()` returns `[3.5, 2.83, 3.25, 1.5]`

`extent()` returns `[1.5, 3.5]`

In case you need absolute minimum and maximum for all properties of the `data`, you should concatenate arrays:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain(d3.extent(
    [].concat(data.map(function (item) {
        return (item.glazed);
    }), data.map(function (item) {
        return (item.jelly);
    }), data.map(function (item) {
        return (item.powdered);
    }), data.map(function (item) {
        return (item.sprinkles);
    }))))
   .range([0, width]);
```

Finally, if you have a list of valuable properties, you should replace `[].concat(...)` expression by anonymous function and call it immediately like this: `function(array, names){...}(data, temp)`. You should know, in JavaScript `array.property` and `array["property"]` -- are the same calls.

```
var temp = ["glazed", "jelly", "powdered", "sprinkles"];
var width = 1000;
var data = [{glazed: 3.50, jelly: 4.50, powdered: 1.00, sprinkles: 3.50, age: 21, responses: 2,name:"test"},
    {glazed: 2.83, jelly: 3.50, powdered: 1.83, sprinkles: 4.50, age: 22, responses: 6,name:"test"},
    {glazed: 3.25, jelly: 4.75, powdered: 2.25, sprinkles: 3.50, age: 23, responses: 4,name:"test"},
    {glazed: 1.50, jelly: 4.00, powdered: 2.50, sprinkles: 4.00, age: 25, responses: 2,name:"test"}];


var x = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain(d3.extent(
       function(array, names){
          var res = [];
          array.forEach(function(item){
             names.forEach(function(name){
                res = res.concat(item[name]);
             });
          });
          return(res);
       }(data, temp)
    ))
   .range([0, width]);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/v5qzuuhj/

Comment: but I need a map which will give me all values of glazed, jelly, powdered and sprinkles, not just glazed..

Comment: thanks, just one more thing.. if I have an array above this code temp=["glazed","jelly","powdered","sprinkles"], is it possible to concise ur code such that item.glazed, etc.. come from the data in this array

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to be able to handle any key values except `age`, `responses` and `name`, and that others in addition to `glazed`, `jellied`, `powdered` & `sprinkled` might appear, this approach should work to calculate max and min values:

```
var keys_to_ignore = ["age", "responses", "name"]

data.forEach( function (row)
{
    //Use d3.entries to create key\values
    var data_entries = d3.entries(row)
    // Add the 'current maximum' and 'current_min' based off the previous rows
    // If this is the first row, the extent will be undefined
    if (typeof extent !== "undefined") {
        data_entries.push({"key":"current_max", "value":extent[1]})
        data_entries.push({"key":"current_min", "value":extent[0]})
    }
    // now calculate the extent (max / min)
    extent = d3.extent(data_entries, function (d) {
        // Ignore specified keys
        if (keys_to_ignore.indexOf(d.key) == -1) {
            return d.value;
        }
    });
});

console.log(extent)
```

Using [`d3.entries`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries) will create objects with a key and value attribute, making the data easier to manage.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/aa4d0z81/

I feel like there's a more elegant way to do this, but I haven't managed to figure it out

Comment: The max is coming right but min is 0 rather than 1.5

Comment: Thanks - good point. I've updated the answer to not set the initial minimum (I originally was setting it to 0, and looking for values lower than that). Fiddle also updated